# Floor function gave different answers for the same number

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
math.floor(10**62 * (1-3/(10**31)))
output: 100000000000000003502199685943161173046080317798311825604870144

math.floor(10**62-3*(10**31))
output:99999999999999999999999999999970000000000000000000000000000000


10**62 * (1-3/(10**31)) - (10**62-3*(10**31))
output: 0.0
```

I wanted to check my answer for a number theory problem and I'm getting two different floors of the same number. What is going wrong?

Comment: ``float`` is limited precision. Their difference being zero does not mean equality, it means the difference is smaller than the precision. Compare ``(10**62 * (1-3/(10**31))) == (10**62-3*(10**31))`` and ``int(10**62 * (1-3/(10**31))) - int(10**62-3*(10**31))``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)